# How to prevent GameObject from detecting unreferenced collision

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating an endless runner game where the basic idea is to avoid spikes and collect gems -- pretty basic. The problem I am having is that whenever the player collides with the gem, even though it destroys the gem, plays the collection animation and adds 1 to the score counter, it also acts like a spike and destroys the player. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Here is my code for "GemTypeCollision.cs":

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GemTypeCollision : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject gem;
    public Collider2D gemCollider;
    public float numberOfGems;
    public Animator gemAnimator;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D gemCollider)
    {
        numberOfGems += 1;
        gemAnimator.SetBool("gemCollected", true);
        Destroy(gem, 0.5f);
    }
}
```

I also think it worth noting that the player also has a "spike type collision" script attached as well, and the player is reacting exactly as he would if he were to hit a spike, even while the gem is being destroyed. It seems to think the gem is of type spike as well as type gem, but I'm not entirely sure.

Question update:

Here is the real problem -- when the player collides with anything, Unity thinks he is colliding with everything, like the OnTriggerEnter2D method, instead of taking the Collider2D parameter I am giving it, it is just ignoring the information and thinking the player is triggered by every collider at once. Does someone know a way to fix that problem?

Comment: Can you verify that the SpikeTypeCollision is called as well when either object is collided with?

Comment: Show the code that you use to detect spike collisions.

Answer (score 1):

From the code you posted I simply guess you do the same mistake in the player spike collision script as here:

You don't check if the collision actually happens with the correct object type so both scripts will react to any collider trigger.

---

You should [Tag](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) your objects appropriately like e.g. "Spike" and "Gem" and than do

```c#
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D gemCollider)
{
    // You should always check e.g. via a tag
    // if it's not a Gem -> do nothing
    if(gemCollider.tag != "Gem") return;

    // or alternatively if there is a certain component on the collision object you might also do
    if(!gemCollider.GetComponent<GemComponent>()) return;

    // ...
}
```

Now the same also in your spike collision you should add a check like e.g.

```c#
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    // if it's not a spike do nothing
    if(other.tag != "Spike") return;

    // ...
}
```